# ASP.NET - Disable Theme for WebService

Tags: asp.net, themes, asmx

I am experiencing the same issue as described here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1023591.aspx

I have a default page theme set in the `<pages />` element of the root web.config, which,  in addition to the rest of the website, is being applied to WebService .ASMX pages. I would like to prevent ASP.NET from applying the themes to .ASMX pages.

The answer in the above discussion says you can edit 'DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx' in the .NET framework's root CONFIG folder (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\VERSION\CONFIG\DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx) and specify `<%@ Page Theme="" %>`, but this only works if you are able to access that file on the server.

I have tried adding a `<location />` element to the web.config which points at a specific .ASMX file, but that seems to be ignored as the .ASMX page is still being themed.

Is there any way to prevent ASP.NET from applying application themes to .ASMX files which works without modifying the system-level 'DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx' (mentioned above)?

**Edit**

I am able to work around this by allowing my base page type to define the applied theme, but even despite my workaround, I am wondering if there is a 'correct' way to override this rather ridiculous behavior in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

How about removing the line from the web.config and adding a line to your base page (hopefully you have one), that sets your default theme.  If you still want to manage via web.config, you could add a appSettings entry for this theme value.

Example:

```
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreInit(e);
        this.Theme = <Enter Your Theme Here>;
    }
```

Comment: Indeed this is the solution which I am using, but I just find it rather peculiar that ASP.NET would behave this way considering one would never want their application-specific styles applied to a generated template for a non-page.

Answer (score 0):

If the .asmx files aren't in the root of the website can't you just put another web.config in their folder and remove the theme there?

Comment: In theory this would work, yes. However in this application the .ASMX files are in the root. I'm looking for a solution that excludes changing the physical location of any files.

Answer (score 0):

Note that .asmx files are not "pages" in any sense. Placing them in a folder which is subject to a directive that takes some action "for all pages" is not appropriate.

Either take the suggestion from [Zachary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/64741/zachary), or the one from [James Gaunt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/178157/james-gaunt).

Or, better yet, stop using ASMX at all, and move to WCF.

Comment: Despite the fact that .asmx files are not pages, it is a root-level `<pages />` element that is causing the behavior in the first place. I would have thought that at the very least I could override it with `<location />`.